# <a> link wont open in the same page

Tags: html

I have an `<a>` link which will only open if I right click it and click on "open in a new tab. If i just click it normally it just puts a "?" after the rest of the link, like this: "http://localhost:8011/login.html?".

**Code:**

```
<div class="login-page">
    <div class="form">
        <form class="login-form">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username" />
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
            <a href="index.html"><button class="login">login</button></a>
            <p class="message">Not registered? <a href="index.html">Create an account</a></p>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

If i put `target="_self"` it still doesn't work. The two files are definitely in the same folder.

Comment: Is this for the `login` link or the `create an account` link?

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your `HTML` form to be as follows so that the form is submitted when `login` is clicked:

```
 <div class="form">
  <form class="login-form" method="POST" action="index.html">

     <!-- user inputs -->
     <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
     <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />

     <!-- your submit button -->
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="login">

     <!-- your other link -->
     <p class="message">Not registered? <a href="index.html">Create an account</a></p>

  </form>
</div>
```

This approach will be better than the current one for creating a login form.

This way you still have your button that will redirect to `index.html` without having to use a messy approach with `<a>` and `<button>`.

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML is invalid. It is forbidden to put a `<button>` inside an `<a>`. [Use a validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/).

The effect you see is due to error recovery reacting badly and your clicks being handled by different elements.

> will only open if I right click it and click on "open in a new tab

This is what happens when you right click on the `<a>` element.

> If i just click it normally it just puts a "?" after the rest of the link

This is what happens when you submit a form using a submit button (and the form has no successful controls in it, which is the case here because none of your controls have `name`s).

---

If you want a link, then use a link and only a link. Get rid of the `<button>` element.

If you want something that looks like a button then first think about what message you are sending to the user. Buttons *do* things. Links *go* places. Giving the user a visual signal that they are *do*ing something is likely to be wrong.

If you still want a link that looks like a button, then style it with CSS.

---

That said, having a link marked Login which doesn't submit the form is just confusing. You should probably:

1. Keep the `<button>`
2. Get rid of the `<a>`
3. Give your form controls `name` attributes
4. Make the form use `method="POST"`

… and then write server side code to process the data so the login form can be used to login to the site.

Comment: He could also just make the `submit` form element his "login" and give the form an action

Answer (score 0):

It's because you've a button, and it's trying to submit the form.

Try using bootstrap and give the `<a>` tag some classes, like this:

```
<div class="login-page">
   <div class="form">
      <form class="login-form">
         <input type="text" placeholder="Username" />
         <input type="password" placeholder="Password" />

         <a href="index.html" class="btn btn-primary">login</a>

         <p class="message">Not registered? <a href="index.html">Create an account</a></p>
      </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or just give style to your `<a>` by css, but if you use the button, then you're submitting the form instead clicking the link.

EDIT: you could also wrap the `<a>` inside the button, so the link on the `<a>` will execute first instead of submitting the form

```
<button class="login"><a href="index.html">login</a></button>
```